# IllegalStateException: Error short name does not include outerclass name

Tags: java, sonarqube

We're facing the following problem when analyzing one of our Java projects:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:14.044s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 22 15:42:24 CET 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 119M/290M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project our-project: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\jenkins-work\jobs\our-project\workspace\Common\src\com\company\appp\AdvApi32Lib.java': Error short name does not include outerclass name : bb -- Function -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project our-project: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\jenkins-work\jobs\our-project\workspace\Common\src\com\company\appp\AdvApi32Lib.java'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\jenkins-work\jobs\our-project\workspace\Common\src\com\company\appp\AdvApi32Lib.java'
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error short name does not include outerclass name : bb -- Function
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Convert.innerClassName(Convert.java:56)
...
```

Do you know how it can be fixed?

We're using SQ 5.3, Java plugin 3.9.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share the contents of the file:  
'D:\jenkins-work\jobs\our-project\workspace\Common\src\com\company\appp\AdvApi32Lib.java'

Comment: The code in AdvApi32Lib.java hasn't changed for years. SonarQube analysis of the project worked fine.
Maybe the problem has to do with SQ 5.3. We updated to the newest SQ version in the last weeks.

Comment: Outer class name: bb indicates some kind of obfuscation. Is it possible that there is a bug in the obfuscation process? Do you have access to the sources after obfuscation?

Comment: We face the same problem using SQ 5.4. The code in question belongs to a 3rd party library (ChartDirector), hence it cannot be changed.
Stack trace is here: http://pastebin.com/PgnVjsre